# I was doing Machine Learning and i got stuck at one of the line of list comprehension

Tags: python, machine-learning

```
image_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=45)

train_data_gen = image_gen.flow_from_directory(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                               directory=train_dir,
                                               shuffle=True,
                                               target_size=(IMG_SHAPE, IMG_SHAPE))

**augmented_images = [train_data_gen[0][0][0] for i n range(5)]**

plotImages(augmented_images)
```

I am unable to understand why ploting the images we are getting 5 different images as we are using the same index .Isn't the 5 images be same?  ( train_data_gen[0][0][0] )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked it up and found the [Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator), assuming this is from Keras. From the documentation:

```
rotation_range: Int. Degree range for random rotations.
```

The data is going to be randomly generated. If you want reproducible results, I recommend setting a seed.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible to say with certainty without knowing what library `ImageDataGenerator` comes from, but the name of the class suggests its a generator. As a result, repeatedly accessing `train_data_gen[0][0][0]` may yield a different value every time it is accessed.

As an illustration of that idea:

```
from random import randint


class MyIndexedGenerator:
    @staticmethod
    def random_generator():
        while True:
            yield randint(1, 10)

    def __init__(self):
        self.values = self.random_generator()

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return next(self.values) + index


example_gen = MyIndexedGenerator()
result = [example_gen[0] for i in range(5)]
print(result)
```

Can yield (for example):

```
[7, 1, 8, 7, 7]
```